# Short URL for comments

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

When posting, users have access to shortened URLs for questions (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/q/7498413/117870`) and also answers (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/a/27171218/117870`). These can be very useful when posting links in comments.

If, however, one desires to link to another comment, there appears to be no shortened URL. Thus, users have to contend with links like this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms#comment42833046_7501638`.

These can sometimes be very long and can fairly quickly eat up the character allocation in comments.

I would like to know if there is any way of getting a shortened URL for comments posted across the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Actually, there is already a shortened URL, it's used in the notifications.

Comment: Btw, last part of short q and a links is your user id, which can be omitted. Just http://stackoverflow.com/q/7498413

Comment: @nicael: I am aware of that, thank you. I decided to leave it in just because as stated [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277770/117870), *"The user ID is how the system knows that you're the sharer."* It's not particularly useful within the Stack Exchange network but it can come in handy if the link is copied directly to another [unrelated] site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is already such a short URL, in the format of:

```
http://{site}/posts/comments/{comment id}
```

For example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/798177